# Remove gap between columns in flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having some trouble with a flexbox layout. What I'm trying to achieve is how the image below is positioned. However, using margin and padding I can move the elements to the correct place without something drastic happening.

I am probably approaching this incorrectly. If someone could give me some advice and an explanation on how to do this correctly that would be great.

***Wireframe***

[image]

***How it is right now***

[image]

***HTML***

```
<div style="background: grey;">
    <div class="parent-container" style="flex-direction: column; align-items: center; margin: 10px;">
        <div class="aelia-text child33">
            The first of it's kind, to<br/>
            create a better customer<br/>
            journey with reduced<br/>
            collection waiting time and<br/>
            a special moment that makes<br/>
            even the most jet-lagged<br/>
            shopper smile.
        </div>
        <div class="child33">
            <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/Aelia_Robot_highres006.jpg)'}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="child33">
            <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/AELIA_IMAGE.jpg)'}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.aelia-text {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-family: portland-medium-font; 
    -ms-flex-pack: center; 
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.child33 {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50%;
    width: 33.3%;
    max-width: calc(100% * (1/3));
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex-flow: nowrap row;
    -o-flex-flow: nowrap row;
    flex-flow: nowrap row;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

.parent-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 92vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.img-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your flex container (`.parent-container`) has three children (flex items).

Each child has a class `child33`.

The flex container is set to `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`, meaning the items will align vertically and wrap when necessary, forming new columns.

```
.parent-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 92vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

<div class="parent-container" style="flex-direction: column; align-items: center; ...">
```

So in your image you have a two-column layout: two items in the first column, and the third item wraps to form the second.

***The reason both columns are spread out*** is that an initial setting of a flex container is [**`align-content: stretch`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property). This means that multiple lines in the [*cross axis*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276) will be distributed evenly across the length of the container.

You already have `align-items: center` in your code. But this only works on single line flex containers. When there are multiple lines in the cross-axis, you need to use `align-content`.

***So, override the default setting by adding `align-content: center` to your container.***

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.parent-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 92vh;
    width: 100vw;
    align-content: center;  /* NEW */
}

.aelia-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-family: portland-medium-font;
}

.child33 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50%;
    width: 33.3%;
    max-width: calc(100% * (1/3));
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* added image for demo; original code had relative URI */
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: grey;">
    <div class="parent-container">
        <div class="aelia-text child33">
            The first of it's kind, to
            <br/> create a better customer
            <br/> journey with reduced
            <br/> collection waiting time and
            <br/> a special moment that makes
            <br/> even the most jet-lagged
            <br/> shopper smile.
        </div>
        <div class="child33">
            <div class="img-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="child33">
            <div class="img-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14gxjfum/)

*From the spec:*

> [**6. Flex Lines**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-lines)
>
> In a multi-line flex container (even one with only a single line), the
>   cross size of each line is the minimum size necessary to contain the
>   flex items on the line (after alignment due to `align-self`), and the
>   lines are aligned within the flex container with the `align-content`
>   property. ***In a single-line flex container, the cross size of the line
>   is the cross size of the flex container, and `align-content` has no
>   effect.*** The main size of a line is always the same as the main size of
>   the flex container’s content box.
>
> [**8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within
>   the flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis,
>   similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the
>   main-axis. ***Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex
>   container.***
>
> *<sub>(emphasis added)</sub>*

Comment: Appreciate the Fiddle and explanation on why it wasn't working as I didn't realise this before. As you stated adding align-content: center; did indeed work as intended and fix my issue. I know you're not meant to say thanks on SO :D but ya know...

Comment: @Michael_B You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly, you want to center both columns in the middle. Since `.parent-container` has `flex-direction: column;` in your inline style, you would need `justify-content: center;`.

If you look in the section 'Basics & Terminologiy' in [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), you'll see that justify-content plays with the main axis of the flexbox and align-items plays with the cross axis. So when your flexbox direction is in columns and you want to horizontally center you columns, you need to align them in the main axis or with the justify-content attribute.

But if you want to make your flexbox cross-browser you would need the following:

```
-webkit-justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
```